# Problems setting up a new theme in Ipython?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use another theme for Ipython notebook so I following this [instructions](https://github.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook) the problem is I'm in OSX and I dont have the wget, I installed it homebrew. Could somebody help me to set ipython notebooks in a dark theme?. I tried this:

```
brew /Users/user/.ipython/profile_notebooks/static/custom/custom.css
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook/master/base16-ocean-dark.css
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `curl` or by manually downloading the theme. I have given steps for both the options below.

Create a custom profile using the following command:

```
ipython profile create ocean
```

Replace the content of the default stylesheet `custom.css` with that of the required theme using the following command

**Using curl:**

```
curl -o `ipython locate profile ocean`/static/custom/custom.css https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook/master/base16-ocean-dark.css
```

Start the `IPython` notebook by specifying the custom profile e.g.

```
ipython notebook --profile=ocean
```

---

**Alternative:**

If you are not able to download using `curl`, you can simply download the `base16-ocean-dark.css` and replace the `custom.css` in the custom directory of your created profile.

Locate the profile directory:

```
ipython locate profile ocean
```

Go to its `static/custom` directory and replace the content of `custom.css` with that of downloaded `css` file.
Start the `IPython` notebook by specifying the custom profile as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

Amit's answer isn't fit for `ipython=>4.0`, as `jupyter` is divided from it now.

You can try [jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes).
It is suit for `ipython=>4.0` and much more easy to install.

> **Install jupyter-themes**
>
> ```
> $ pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes
> ```
>
> **Pick a theme and install**
>
> ```
> # list themes (located in ~/.jupyter-themes)
> $ jt -l
>
> # install theme (-t) for jupyter nb
> # theme names: oceans16 | grade3 | space-legos
> $ jt -t grade3
>
> # install a theme (-t) with toolbar (-T) enabled
> $ jt -T -t grade3
>
> # install a theme (-t) and set font-size (-f), default value is 11
> $ jt -f 12 -t grade3
>
> # reset (-r) to default for jupyter theme
> $ jt -r
> ```

Comment: Hey, I did what you've suggested, but get an issue "Theme grade3 not found. Available: " and empty list follows, apparently. I looked into `jupyterthemes/__init__.py` and there this error appears when get_theme() method returns the list of themes that does not contain grade3. But to be honest, I have a feeling it looks in a wrong directory. At the same time, I could not install it from git, so I installed it from the zip file - not sure whether there is expected to be any difference.

Comment: @llya Do you have `.jupyter`, `.jupyter-themes` folders in user home?  And there need a `custom` folder under `.jupyter`. PS: I am using windows, maybe other os would have some different.

Comment: I am also using Windows. I only have `.jupyter` folder there, with a single file `migrated` with no extension.

Comment: I've created the `.jupyter-themes` folder there (you need to create a folder `.jupyter-themes.` with an additional dot in the end, it is removed by Windows Explorer), and copied there .css files from git. Then it worked. I don't understand how could this folder be created automatically though.

Comment: @Ilya maybe you should post an issue to jupyter-themes.In my case, just install it and all done

Answer (score 2):

I've added jupyter-themes to pypi under the name jupyterthemes.

To install the latest version:

```
#uninstall any old versions
pip uninstall jupyter-themes 
#install the latest version (no hyphen)
pip install jupyterthemes
```

Hopefully that takes care of any issues people were having with themes not showing up (@llya).