# iPython custom theme not working on notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I set up the ocean dark theme for my ipython notebook by following the instructions in the accepted answer here: [Problems setting up a new theme in Ipython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954158/problems-setting-up-a-new-theme-in-ipython).
The answer above has the wrong link, so I used

```
curl -o `ipython locate profile ocean`/static/custom/custom.css https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook/master/ipython-2/output/base16-ocean-dark.css
```

The theme works fine on the directory page, but when I actually open the notebook, it looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output cells (and lots of other stuff) isn't dark.  Try doing something like this

```
div.output_area pre {
    background-color: black; font-weight: normal; color: #c0c5ce;
}
div.output_subarea {
    background-color: black; font-weight: normal; color: #c0c5ce;
}
```

Those lines are already in the file except the background-color isn't specified.

What I do is put the file in the same dir as my notebooks and load them like this

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML(open("dark.css", "r").read())
```

You have to put `<style>..</style>` tags at the beginning and end of the file, or put it in the HTML if you want to leave the file intact.

```
HTML("<style>" + open("dark.css", "r").read() + "</style>")
```

This way you can reload the css by just running the cell.  So edit the css file, save it, reload - now see your changes right away.  If you like it for the default then overwrite your custom.css.

If you really like black you can try `*{background-color: black;}` in the css file